# AlpineJS X-ref Binding to display HTML from another file

Tags: alpine.js

I am currently learning Alpine JS and trying to find examples of binding using x-ref ( As per to the Docs: https://github.com/alpinejs/alpine#x-ref )but there isn't many as it only became a feature late year year.  I am just wondering could anyone provide an example on how to x-ref a variable so it can be used in a `Fetch` Method.

Currently I am not using x-ref and using `x-html` which is not rendering the HTML code for some reason, so I'm hoping by using x-ref it will work(?)

```
 <div x-data="foo()" x-init="init()" >
              <div> 
                <template x-for="foo in list" :key="foo.id">
                  <button
                    @click="activeTab = itemfooid"
                    x-text="foo.name"
                    x-ref="foo.name"
                    x-on:click="getHTML( item )"
                  >
                </template>
        <div x-ref="myxRef" x-show="activeTab === 0" x-html ="foo[0].name"> post </div>   
  </div>
```

**Fetch Foo**

```
function foo(){
    activeTab: 0, // Set active tab to POST 
    list: [],
 init(){
     this.list =    { id: 1, name: 'foo', code: 'null' }, 
 }
}


  getHTML( foo){
          fetch('url/example.html')
                          .then(response => response.text() )
                          .then(html => {
                          
                             if( foo.code=== undefined ){
                               foo.code= html

                             }

                          })
                          .catch( error => console.log ( error ) ) 
                 
        },
```

Example HTML:

```
<code language-php> $test = 1 <div x-if="country === undefined"> echo "Hey"; </div> return $test </code>
```

My code will only have the code brackets and the rest inside will be plain text.

Below is an example I found on which I'm trying to follow but that doesn't work either. https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/javascript/laravel-alpinejs-fetch-and-x-ref

```
<div x-ref="test" class="window-content"></div>

<script>
    function windowManager()
            fetch('/frontend/blog')
                .then(response => response.text())
                .then(html => { this.$refs.test.innerHTML = html })
        }
</script>
```

Comment: I can't see where you are using `foo.code` in your html. Is there part of your code missing?

Comment: Agreed with @SteveO, you should rewrite and clarify your question, and explain what you are trying to achieve here.